# How to get matches from a text file using Php with a specified start and end point?

Tags: php, regex

I have a Php script which is using the `preg_match_all` function to return all the matches from a text file. But, I want the function to only check for a match starting at position 3 with a length of 11 digits (basically, with ending position at 13) in each line instead of looking for the match in the entire line as that will return false results.

Script:

```
<?php
$file = 'masterfile.out';
$searchfor = '02354098780';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

// search, and store all matching occurrences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo substr(implode("\n", $matches[0]),2,11);
   echo substr(implode("\n", $matches[0]),166,11);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
?>
```

Text file sample data:

```
I0023540987805R01  ABC                         GHI                       OLirrt                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1098833   1990041300000001086000000000108600000000000996000000000032100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006589000000000000000                                     P0012B    
 0000002032902R01  DEF                         JKL                       KLijuI                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1029132   1997010800000002396000000000239600000120002326000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004560000000000000000000000000987600000000                                     A203SD
```

Comment: Could you post the content of the text file?

Comment: @tcj sure, I am adding it to the post.

Comment: I the text file example does 02354098780 exist? where should it appear? on any line starting position 3 yes? also , where do the line end in the example?on : P0012B?

Comment: @Shlomtzion yes, the value: 02354098780 can be found on line 1 starting at position 3. Line 1 ends at P0012B  . Line 2 starts at  0000002032902R01 in the given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your example is close to your intended use, you're essentially searching for an exact match of a substring, but using preg_match_all. However, iterating over the lines should have lower memory-impact, and strict substring-comparison for exact equality has lower cpu-impact than preg_match_all.

So I would recommend doing that. This can be achieved either with `fgets`or with `stream_get_line`, which might be slightly more performant (though that should not matter in most contexts).

This can be achieved as follows:

```
$searchString = 'someFixedString';
$posOffset = 2;
$matchLength = mb_strlen($searchString);
$filePath = '/some/file.path';
$fileHandle = @fopen($filePath, 'r+');
$checkedLines = 0;
$matches = [];
$foundMatches = false;

//Depending on what you wish to output
$capturePosOffset = 0;
$captureLength = $matchLength + $posOffset + 3;

// if lines are  no longer than 8192 bytes,
// otherwise set to a value above the byte-length of your lines
$maxBytesToReadPerLine = 0; 

// if file line-terminator is as in PHP, 
// otherwise set to file's line-terminator
$lineTerminator = PHP_EOL;

if ($fileHandle) {
    while (!feof($fileHandle)) {
       $checkedLines++;
       // or just use fgets, which requires no further arguments
       $line = stream_get_line($fileHandle, $maxBytesToReadPerLine, $lineTerminator);
       if (mb_substr($line, $posOffset, $matchLength) === $searchString) { 
           $foundMatches = true;
           $matches[] = $line;
           // Or, if you want to capture a field with a fixed Length
           // (modify the offset and length arguments above)
           $matches[] = mb_substr($line, $capturePosOffset, $captureLength);
       }
    }
}
if ($foundMatches) {
    echo "Found " . count($matches) . " matches among $checkedLines lines:" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($matches as $matchedValue) {
        // I'm not sure what you intend to do here.
        // - In your example code, it appears you
        // implode the array, but then only output
        // 11 characters of the first line starting at position 3.
        // If you want the whole line, you can capture it above
        // and echo it here.

        // Or if you want, you can capture and output the first field
        // by modifying $capturePosOffset and $captureLength
        // by merely echoing the value (and a newline)
        echo '  ' . $matchedValue . PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    echo "No matches found!" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

We use `mb_strlen` and `mb_substr` in case the encoding allows for multi-byte characters - only if you know that this is definitely not the case can `strlen` and `substr` be safely used.

One ought not to get bogged down in premature optimization, but just as a note: which solution is the most optimal will depend heavily on the file-size and the match-length.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have updated the post. I need to echo the 11 digits starting at position 3, and then, 11 digits starting at position 166 of the matched line.

Comment: I see. In that case, you can just modify the `$matches[] = ...` code in my example. Though it seems you're still capturing and outputting the fixed search-string for each match. Since you already know what you're searching for, you might not need to output that at all, or you might only output the search-string once in the beginning - in that case you'd only need `$matches[] = mb_substr($line, 166, 11);`

Comment: I tried that but I am getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: stream_get_line() expects at least 2 arguments

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry - my mistake. [`stream_get_line`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php) requires a max-byte-length-to-read as a second parameter and has an optional third line-terminator parameter. You can use [`fgets`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) which requires no argument other than the file-handle, or use `stream_get_line` as in my modified example - with a second argument at least as long as the max byte-length of your lines and the file's line-terminator as a third argument.

Comment: perfecto! It is working great. Just a minor issue, it is only echoing the first matched result not the other matches.

Comment: For debugging, you may want to increment a counter at the beginning of the body of the `while` loop and then output that later - to check if you're reading all lines separately (I'll adapt my example shortly).

If you're reading all lines, you ought to check how many matches you're getting - e.g. with `echo 'Found ' . count($matches) . ' matching lines: ' . PHP_EOL;` instead of just echoing "Found matches:" - (if you add only one entry per found line. If you add two entries per match, then you should divide by two first).

Answer (score 2):

For a small number of characters, you can *anchor* the regular expression to the beginning of a line:

```
'#^..([0-9]{13})#'
```

will search for 13 digits, ignoring the first two characters (.) from the beginning (^) of the line, and including the third.

In this case:

```
<?php
$file      = 'masterfile.out';
// $pattern   = '#^..([0-9]{11})#m'; // Any 11 digits
$pattern   = '#^..(02354098780)#m';   // Exactly these 11

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this
// as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exists)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[1]);
   echo "\n";
} else {
   echo "No matches found\n";
}
```

## update

I've just noticed that your sequence starts on the third character *beginning at 1*. In some standards (and in my early example) you start counting at 0. So if you start from 1, you need only **two** dots, not three. In other words, when you say "starting at position 3", you probably mean to skip the **first two** characters, while - as you can see from the other answers - almost everyone assumed you wanted to skip *three* characters.

Comment: where do I put this?

Comment: added (modified) sample code to answer. I included the 11-digit regex, since you said 11 digits, but your code only searches for 2354098780.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach from yours a bit - Since we are looking for a string in a specific part of the line we can remove the rest and check if the string appears in said line.

```
    <?php


$text = "I0023540987805R01  ABC                         GHI                       OLirrt                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1098833   1990041300000001086000000000108600000000000996000000000032100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006589000000000000000                                     P0012B    
0000002032902R01  DEF                         JKL                       KLijuI                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1029132   1997010800000002396000000000239600000120002326000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004560000000000000000000000000987600000000                                     A203SD   ";

echo '<pre>';
$txt = explode("\n",$text);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($txt);

foreach($txt as $key => $line){
    $subbedString = substr($line,2,11);

    $searchfor = '02354098780';
    //echo strpos($subbedString,$searchfor); 
    if(strpos($subbedString,$searchfor) === 0){
        $matches[$key] = $searchfor;
        $matchesLine[$key] = $line; /**Save the whole line when match is found. */
        echo "Found in line : $key";
    }

    
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matchesLine);
```

Will return:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => I0023540987805R01  ABC                         GHI                       OLirrt                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1098833   1990041300000001086000000000108600000000000996000000000032100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006589000000000000000                                     P0012B    
    [1] => 0000002032902R01  DEF                         JKL                       KLijuI                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1029132   1997010800000002396000000000239600000120002326000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004560000000000000000000000000987600000000                                     A203SD   
)
Found in line : 0
Array
(
    [0] => 02354098780
)
Array
(
    [0] => I0023540987805R01  ABC                         GHI                       OLirrt                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1098833   1990041300000001086000000000108600000000000996000000000032100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006589000000000000000                                     P0012B    
)
```

Comment: perfect! but, how do I return the entire line when there is a match. thank you.

Comment: I added : $matchesLine[$key] = $line; in the loop when the if is true this will create and populate the array with $key - line number and $line as the line itself.

Comment: or just echo $line - inside the loop there and you will see it ...

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression ignores the first 3 characters at the beginning of each line and captures the subsequent 11

https://regex101.com/r/MEaB67/1

```regex
/^.{3}(.{11})/gm
```

**EDIT**

Here is some sample PHP code to test the regular expression

```php
<pre>
<?php
$pattern = '/^.{3}(.{11})/m';
$subject = '
I0023540987805R01  ABC                         GHI                       OLirrt                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1098833   1990041300000001086000000000108600000000000996000000000032100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006589000000000000000                                     P0012B    
 0000002032902R01  DEF                         JKL                       KLijuI                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1029132   1997010800000002396000000000239600000120002326000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004560000000000000000000000000987600000000                                     A203SD   
';
$matches = null;
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
</pre>
```

Fabio

Comment: where do I add this?

Comment: @JackYuan, you can assign it to the `$pattern` variable – hold on while I add some sample PHP code to my answer, please

Comment: @JackYuan, here you go

Comment: thank you @Fabio but that returns all the values not the matching value that has been assigned to the searchfor vairable.

Comment: @JackYuan, I see: I thought you would first get the matches and then search for your value in the array. I like this approach better because the regex is more general

Answer (score 0):

You can match 3 characters, then use `\K` to forget what is matched so far and then match 11 digits.

```
^...\K\d{11}
```

- `^` Start of string
- `...` Match 3 times any char except a newline
- `\K` Clear the current match buffer
- `\d{11}` Match 11 digits

You can omit using `preg_quote` as there is nothing to escape in the current pattern.

As the pattern uses an anchor `^` you have to specify the multiline flag `/m` to get all the results.

```
$file = 'masterfile.out';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = "/^...\K\d{11}/m";

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)) {
    echo "Found matches:" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($matches[0] as $m) {
        echo $m . PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    echo "No matches found";
}
```

Output

```
Found matches:
23540987805
00002032902
```